# How to create a method that accepts 2 objects of the same Type, a property, and compares the values

Tags: c#, compare

I'm trying to create a helper function (for a class) that accepts 2 objects and compares a property on both classes

These properties are only ever simple types like `string`, `int` and `bool`

**Usage**

```
Compare(widget1,widget2,x => x.Name)
```

**What i have so far**

```
  private void CompareValue<T>(Order target, Order source, Func<Order, T> selector)
  {
     if(target.selector != source.selector)
     {
       // do some stuff here
     }
  }
```

Obviously the code above doesn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a constraint to [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void CompareValue<T>(Order target, Order source, Func<Order, T> selector)
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    if (!selector(target).Equals(selector(source))
    {
        // ... Do your stuff
    }
}
```

This would handle the types you specified (as well as many others), and allow the compiler protect you from use cases where this would likely be inappropriate.

Note that you also need to call the `Func<T,U>`, ie: `selector(target)` and `selector(source)`, to create the resulting value.

Comment: I was hoping for a cool `nameof` trick that would allow eliminating the lambda expression. No such luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a fully generic version:

```
public void CompareValue<TModel,TProperty>(TModel x, TModel y, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    where TModel : class
    where TProperty : IEquatable<TProperty>
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    Type modelType = typeof(TModel);
    PropertyInfo propInfo = modelType.GetProperty(memberExpression.Member.Name);

    TProperty xValue = (TProperty)propInfo.GetValue(x);
    TProperty yValue = (TProperty)propInfo.GetValue(y);
    if (xValue.Equals(yValue))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match!");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
CompareValue(widget1, widget2, x => x.Name);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for string, memberExpression is null.. Am I using it incorrectly? (example https://dotnetfiddle.net/5JDkAR)

Comment: correct, this seems to work when TModel is an object and the expression is targeting a property, however my skills aren't such to work out why

Comment: @Default: Defeating the purpose of the expression if you're just comparing straight-up objects aren't you? If you want to compare `x` vs `y` straight, you probably only need a `CompareValue<T>(T x, T y) where T : IEquatable<T>` method signature. The expression is there to reference properties.